# SQLite Update a column from one table using another table

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, sqlite

OK, I am new to SQLite and already doing this successfully using the following query:

```
 UPDATE stuff
 SET UserName = (SELECT UserName FROM Temp_Stuff WHERE Temp_Stuff.EmpID = stuff.EmployeeID
```

This works great when `stuff` has 4995 rows and `Temp_Stuff` has 1814 rows and executes in approximately 2 seconds.

When I try this exact same query when `stuff` has 60,000 rows and `Temp_Stuff` has 55,000 rows, it seems to lock up during the query and does not process anything (I waited for over 20 minutes.)

I am using vb.net to achieve this, and have wrapped the ExecuteNonQuery method in a transaction, and I rollback the transaction if any errors occur (I do not reach this point.) Is there a more efficient way to achieve this in SQLite? I have attempted and realized that joins are not allowed in Update statements, so that idea was thrown out. This seems to be a SQLite specific issue.

****Query Plan:****

```
0   0   0   SCAN TABLE stuff(~1000000 rows)
0   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 0
0   0   0   SCAN TABLE Temp_Stuff(~100000 rows)
```

Comment: could you `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN...` for your statement and add to your question?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal not - you cannot `update` with `join` using SqlLite

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I stated in my post that I tried that (being a SQLite newby) and was not successful.

Comment: Does `Temp_Stuff` have an index on the `EmpID` column?

Comment: Unforuntately not. Currently, I use the EmployeeID/EmpID columns as the natural primary key.

Comment: Is SQLite THAT sensitive to an integer based surrogate key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query plan shows that the `Temp_Stuff` table is *completely* scanned for *every* record in the `stuff` table.

Add an index on the `EmpID` column so that the lookup runs faster.
(For slightly higher performance, use a covering index on both the `EmpID` and `UserName` columns.)

SQLite never automatically creates indexes for named tables; you have to define them explicitly, or implicitly with `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraints.

Comment: Thanks! The issue is that I needed to set the EmployeeID/EmpID columns as primary keys. Afterwards, executed in 7.4 seconds. I love SQLite. Thanks again!